# Mysqli query in one line

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, mysqli

The current procedure I am using to run a simple SQL query is the following:

```
$a = $mysqli->query("SELECT column FROM table");
$b = $a->fetch_assoc();
$c = $b["column"];
```

This uses 3 different variable names and it gets frustrating trying to come up with suitable names.
I think that in the procedural style, I can run this in two lines as oppose to three:

```
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table"));
$b = $a["column"];
```

Is there any approach to use the object-oriented style in just one line of code?

Comment: This isn't a good idea because it will attempt to do mysql_fetch_assoc even if mysql_query fails, and it will make error checking harder. You should also move away from the deprecated mysql_* functions and to PDO or mysqli, to make sure your code will still work with future versions of PHP.

Comment: The normal pattern is `prepare`, `bind` and `execute`, where the `bind` call is only relevant if you have values to add to the query. Putting this on one line is reckless, you're making *way* too many assumptions. PDO has a mode which throws exceptions which is probably worth using if you prefer this style as errors will bubble up, whereas here you're completely ignoring return codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use OOP that you are already using? If I'm not mistaken, you could use the facade design pattern. This is not exactly one line of code but it is more of a write once.

Create an object to do the querying.

```
//This is just a rough idea
class SimpleQuery {

    protected $mysqli;

    function __construct() {
       //Get a connection using whatever way you want
    }

    /**
     * @param string $query The query to execute
     * @param string $field The field to return(optional)
     * @return mixed
     */
    function query($query, $field = NULL) {

      $a = $this->mysqli->query($query);
      $b = $a->fetch_assoc($a);

      //Obviously this function needs to be adjusted to do what you seek, get multiple rows perhas
      if ($field) {
         return $b[$field];
      } else {
         return $b;
      }

    }

}
```

Then you can simply just:

```
$simpleQuery = new SimpleQuery();

$dbData = $simpleQuery->query('SELECT column FROM table','column');
```

Don't know if this works for you but it's worth writing. The reason objects were created, to be reusable. :-)

Comment: While this achieves the goal, it also introduces a wrapper class that obscures what is actually going on. From that point of view, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Quite contrary, such a wrapper class is the only proper answer to the question given.

Comment: @ZombieHunter It's only a rough sketch on how to go about it. A lot of stuff can be done to improve it. I just kept it in the scope of the code the OP provided.

Comment: @ZombieHunter not that great I'd say. I see no point in repeating the column name twice for example.

Comment: I quite like this actually. It's the best answer given and with a few tweaks and error catching, it could be a good alternative. Thanks very much!

Comment: The main problem with this code - it doesn't support placeholders. And scarcely can.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any approach to use the object-oriented style in just one line of code?

Sure.
**This is what object-oriented style exactly for.**

However, you don't quite understand the idea of the object-oriented style.
The idea is, actually, is not to throw some OO-methods together to get some awkward and unreliable construct, but **to create a class**, which will have **methods for all your needs.**

@Touch's is absolutely right with his answer, but of course it's only a sketch. Such a class have to be extended to have all the methods you need:

Say, to have a column from table,

```
$a = $db->getOne("SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 1");
```

Or to get a whole row:

```
$row = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");
```

or all the rows

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table");
```

You may note that these snippets is not only shorter than silly approaches from other answers, but also have error reporting, query logging, profiling and many other useful things implemented already.

You should also take into account that **placeholders** support is **a must!** Otherwise all this stuff will be totally **useless**. Note that dedicated OO-based solution is **the only** way to keep the code in one line: with raw API methods you'll end up not with one but with **dozen lines** at the very least.

Yet such a class can keep one-liners all right:

```
$name = $db->getOne('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ?i',$_GET['id']);
$data = $db->getInd('id','SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE id IN ?a','table', array(1,2));
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE mod=?s LIMIT ?i",$table,$mod,$limit);
```

[Here is an example of a class I am talking about.](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), which you can use already.

Comment: Interesting idea, although probably a bit too complicated for what I want to do.

Comment: it's indeed quite complicated if you're going to write the whole thing from scratch. But luckily, it's already written. You can just download it and start using one-liners in a second. Though it seems you choose to write from scratch. Good luck then and happy injections.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing stopping you form using

```
$mysqli->query($query)->fetch_assoc()["column"];
```

Typical names are:

- `$a` -- `$result`
- `$b` -- `$row`
- `$c` -- `$column`

Comment: I tried what you wrote above however it doesn't work, it returns an error for the last part: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: just on php5.4... 
$var = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_assoc();
$var["column"]

Answer (score -1):

You should check this query before fetch();

I recommend use this:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table");
    if ($query)
    {
       $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }
    else
    {
     echo mysql_error($query);
    }
```

If you will use one line mysql query for fetch result you have a problem with debug if query fails.